# PHP metaphone implementation bug

Tags: php, c, metaphone

I'm testing a metaphone implementation for C# and comparing its results against the built-in metaphone() function from PHP. However, I've come across a bug (which is [previously documented in PHP's issue tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48711) and discussed on [a mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/php-bugs@lists.php.net/msg124392.html)), but I'm trying to understand the C code behind their bug for my own personal interest.

Basically, according to the metaphone algorithm, most instances of -gh- should be rendered silent. In the specific test case of "wright", I expect (and generate with my own algorithm) a metaphone key of "RT"

```
"wr" => R
"i"  => ignored
"gh" => ignored
"t"  => T

Result: RT
```

However, PHP's metaphone function returns RFT. Clearly, it's converting the -gh- to an F, as if it were at the end of a word (e.g. "rough"), but in the case of the word "wright", this is incorrect, because the -gh- does not come at the end of the word. Looking at the metaphone.c file in the PHP source distribution, I see a few key things:

```
/* These prevent GH from becoming F */
#define NOGHTOF(c)  (ENCODE(c) & 16)    /* BDH */

...

/* Go N letters back. */
#define Look_Back_Letter(n) (w_idx >= n ? toupper(word[w_idx-n]) : '\0')
```

And then on line 342:

```
case 'G':
    if (Next_Letter == 'H') {
        if (!(NOGHTOF(Look_Back_Letter(3)) || Look_Back_Letter(4) == 'H')) {
            Phonize('F');
            skip_letter++;
```

Can someone help me understand what exactly the NOGHTOF function does and why this code is incorrectly rendering an F for the -gh- in "wright"? I'm not really a C guy, so the code isn't at all clear to me.

Comment: Then perhaps someone can submit a patch to the list and get this bug fixed!

Comment: SO needs more questions like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of `NOGHTOF(c)` is actually determined by the code starting at line 81:

```
char _codes[26] = {
        1, 16, 4, 16, 9, 2, 4, 16, 9, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 2, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0
    /*  a  b   c  d   e  f  g  h   i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z */
};

#define ENCODE(c) (isalpha(c) ? _codes[((toupper(c)) - 'A')] : 0)
```

Essentially, a value is assigned for each letter of the alphabet in order (A = 1, B = 16, etc.)  Then `ENCODE` macro checks whether the passed character is a letter; if yes, it returns the corresponding code for that letter, otherwise it returns the `null` character.  (It doesn't really return anything, as this is a macro and is substituted by the compiler at compile time to replace the actual call.)

The way I'm reading the code for `'G'` is this (without trying to understand why):

```
If current letter is G then
    If next letter is H then
        Take "_code" value of a letter three letters back (why?) from the _codes table and check the fifth bit (from the back, naturally)
        If this bit is not set OR if a letter four letters back (why?) is 'H' then
            Add 'F' to the result
            skip one more character (letter 'H' following the 'G')
```

Why it is like this is beyond me though, I'm quite sure somebody had a good reason to write it this way, but it seems an obvious bug to me.

Comment: Thanks. I'm only somewhat familiar with bit level operators. Can you tell me how exactly 'AND'ing a number with 16 clears the last 4 bits?

Comment: First, my mistake, it's not clearing the last 4 bit - it checks whether the fifth bit is set - i'm updating my answer.  Now, you're not dealing with any number, but only with one byte (8 bits): xxxxxxxx in binary; 16 in binary is 00010000; now bitwise AND takes corresponding bits of two numbers and create a new number by setting the corresponding bit to 1 only if both bits are 1.

Comment: Right, I got what the & operator does. I figured it was checking to see if bit 5 was set, but was confused by your answer. Thanks for clearing that up. Having said that, yes, I'm also very unsure why checking whether the third letter before the G is ('B','D','H') would render the -gh- silent. Perhaps there the original coder was targeting a select few words in this manner (bough and dough I get, but  hough?), but no doubt the code is incorrect / buggy as hell. Thanks for the additional insight.